# R - legend: assign multiple colours to the same text

Tags: r, plot, legend, bar-chart

I have an R barplot that has six bars divided into two parts each, and six colours - but several of the colours mean the same thing. How can I assign one text to several colours in the legend? Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Here's the R code for the plot:

```
height<-matrix(c(64.39173921,73.08486662,
                 64.25261321,90.70965993,
                 64.91170611,38.21450776,
                 35.60826079,26.91513338,
                 35.74738679,9.290340073,
                 35.08829389,61.78549224), 
                 nrow=2, ncol=6, byrow=TRUE,
                 dimnames=list(c("Bilateral", "Multilateral"),
                           c("GER \ntotal", "GER \nto LA", "ESP \ntotal", 
                                 "ESP \nto LA", "UK \ntotal", "UK \nto LA")))

tmp <- height
height <- matrix(0,nrow=12,ncol=6)
height[cbind(1:12,rep(1:6,each=2))] <- tmp

colnames(height) <- colnames(tmp)
rownames(height) <- rep(rownames(tmp),6)


barplot(height, beside=FALSE,
        main="Bilateral vs. Multilateral Aid 2004-8 average", 
        ylab="Percentage of aid", ylim=c(0,100),
        col=c("deepskyblue4","deepskyblue",
              "deepskyblue4","deepskyblue",
              "darkolivegreen4","darkolivegreen1",
              "darkolivegreen4","darkolivegreen1",
              "firebrick4", "firebrick1",
              "firebrick4", "firebrick1")
        )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You control the legend exactly:

```
legend("bottom",
       legend = c("Bilateral Aid","","","Other","",""),
       fill = c("deepskyblue4","darkolivegreen4","firebrick4","deepskyblue",
                "darkolivegreen1","firebrick1"),
       bg = "white", ncol = 2)
```

You'll need to create some space for the legend or push it outside the plotting region, but you control which colours appear and what text they are associated with.

[image: barplot figure]

Comment: This would work if each colour meant something different. The problem is, the darker colours (deepskyblue4, darkolivegreen4, firebrick4) mean the same thing, namely 'bilateral share of aid', the lighter ones mean 'multilateral share of aid' - now I'd like to bind three colours each to one text... Don't know if that makes sense and explains what it is I want to do?

Comment: @Bettina Yes is does, your Q didn't read like that. I'll think of an edit.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks ever so much, silly me for not thinking of that!